# Rationale of not using RESTful APIs for Pagination

Tags: php, rest, laravel, laravel-4, pagination

By default, Laravel's [Pagination](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination) generates URL of the form `http://example.com/something?page=2`.

That is, the page number is given as a `GET` variable, as opposed to in a RESTful way.

**Why is it done this way?** What is the benefit of this over something like `http://example.com/something/2/` or `http://example.com/something/page/2/`?

Comment: Because you're `GET`ing page 2 of the index and not `something` number 2 nor the second page of one `something`. Providing it as a variable indicates that it's still the same index page, just modified in some way.

Comment: Easy to remember query string parameters, hard to remember exact order of a given REST API route. Personally, i use a hybrid REST architecture like google does with their api's : `/controller/action(/function)` then query string parameters for everything else. so an example might be `/api/users/all` with subfunctions like `/api/users/all/loggedin` and some extra constraints like `/api/users/all/loggedin?date_start=8/5/2015&date_end=8/6/2015`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://example.com/something/page/2 is not really more RESTful than http://example.com/something?page=2. There's no rule against using query strings in REST, they are a fundamental part of HTTP after all.

http://example.com/something/page/2 may look cleaner, but otoh it's inconsistent with a typical REST URL of http://example.com/something/1 because the pages aren't resources with their own ID. They change over time and they change immediately if other params are supplied.

Think about a longer query string:
http://example.com/something?q=fun&valid=true

If you want to remove the params, would it be http://example.com/something/q/fun/valid/true ? Or should it be http://example.com/something/valid/true/q/fun ? My point is, it's cleaner to consider the path as identifying the resource(s) and the query string is options around how to retrieve and present the resource(s).